# Uploading with AJAX not working, form data empty

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to  make upload work but for some reason the form data going to the server file is giving me empty

Form Code:

```
<form id="uploadxlsx" name="uploadxlsx" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Excel File:</label>
    <input name="excelfile" id="excelfile" class="form-control" data-rule-required="true" data-msg-required="Choose File" type="file">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <button type="button" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="sendFile();">Upload</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

the JS code for the above

```
var xhr, hUploadSpeed;
function sendFile()
{
    document.getElementById("serverresponse").innerHTML = "";//clear previous server response

    var url = "upload.cfm";
    var formData = new FormData(document.getElementById("excelfile"));
    xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.open("POST", url, true);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
        if(xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200)
        {
            alert(xhr.responseText);
            document.getElementById("serverresponse").innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
        }
    }
    xhr.send(formData); //Send to server
}
```

when the dump the server form scope, i get this

http://prntscr.com/gsjbtw

this is the request headers image

```
http://prntscr.com/gsjc3n
```

Comment: submitting a form loads a new page ... you may want to preventDefault action of a submit if you don't want to do that

Comment: i fixed it, thanks it was my silly mistake i was actually calling the form field rather than the form itself